# Call a function only after previous function finishes executing in python

Tags: python, urllib

I currently have two functions for my program, namely `download()` and `convert_to_zip()`.

what `download()` does is that it allows me to download a `.csv` file **obtained after webscraping** to a folder I directed it to, like so:

```
if platform == 'darwin':
    Browser = webdriver.Safari()
else:
    Browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# to navigate to a URL 
Browser.get("http://cve.org/downloads")

# ask the browser to find the element using xpath 
try:
    csv_link = Browser.find_element("xpath", "//td[@data-label='Raw']/a[contains(@href,'.csv')]").get_attribute('href')
    print(csv_link) # just to see if we got the right file. Exception will handle if not found.
except:
    print('File cannot be found.')

# Checker to see which OS, then download it to particular OS's desktop folder
if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
    print("your OS is linux")
    path_to_download_folder = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), "Desktop/INF1002/"))
elif platform == "darwin":
    print("your OS is mac")
    path_to_download_folder = str(os.path.join(Path.home(), "Desktop/INF1002/"))
elif platform == "win32":
    print("your OS is windows")
    # add the path of the "scrapedData" folder so that it will be downloaded there.
    path_to_download_folder = str(os.path.expanduser('~\downloads'))

# just to see what path I am putting the csv file in
print(path_to_download_folder)

# this is what the file's name will be, can be altered to whatever doesn't matter.
fname = 'allitems.csv'

# function to download the csv_link, then define a path to store it.
def download():
    # found this requests library, allows download provided it has a path
    dload = request.urlretrieve(csv_link, path_to_download_folder + fname)
    return dload
```

On the other hand, my `convert_to_zip()` function then finds that same `.csv` file and converts it to a zip file. Below is the code for this:

```
def convert_to_zip():
    with zipfile.ZipFile('allitems.zip', 'w') as my_zip:
        my_zip.write('allitems.csv')
```

However, whenever I callback both functions like this:

```
download()
convert_to_zip()
```

only `download()` is executed and `allitems.csv` will be downloaded in the folder.

What I want, is that once `allitems.csv` is downloaded by the `download()` function, `convert_to_zip()` will then convert it to a zip file in the same folder. I have tried manually calling each function individually and both actually work.

Do take note that `convert_to_zip()` will only work if `allitems.csv` is already present in the folder if not it will throw an error.

How do I ensure that `convert_to_zip()` will execute once `allitems.csv` is downloaded by the `download()` function and already present in the folder?

Comment: By default all functions are called subsequentially. If that does not happen there must be something else causing it that is not present in the code you provided.

Comment: that's what I thought. However, if I call them individually, say I comment out one the ```download()``` callback, ```convert_to_zip()``` will execute but will throw an error because I need the file that is supposedly downloaded by my ```download()``` function.

Comment: What happens if you download the file manually and then run `convert_to_zip()`?

Comment: It zips the file and creates ```allitems.zip``` in the same folder.

Comment: I just tested nearly exactly the same code (downloaded file is different since you didn't provide it) and everything works just fine.

Comment: hmm that's odd, you mean to say it downloads the file and zips it altogether?

Comment: Correct - `import urllib.request
import zipfile

def download():
    dload = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://python.org/', 'pythonorg.html')
    return dload
def convert_to_zip():
    with zipfile.ZipFile('allitems.zip', 'w') as my_zip:
        my_zip.write('pythonorg.html')
download()
convert_to_zip()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248593/discussion-between-brio-tech-and-matszwecja).

Comment: I have now updated the question and added more code for understanding.